# Seaborn Heatmap with month & hour of database entry

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataframe with X rows.
For each row, I have the information of the month (value from 1 to 12) and hour (value from 1 to 24) in separate columns

I need to create a heatmap with seaborn in order to display the number of entries crossed with the month/hour.

I do not manage to do it. Any idea how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import RandomState
import seaborn as sns



state = RandomState(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({"month":state.randint(1,12,20),
              "hour":state.randint(1,24,20)
              })

sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(df["month"], df["hour"]), cmap ="Reds",linewidths=1);
```

[image]